# Edit lots of profiles in iTerm2

Tags: terminal, unix, ssh, iterm

A longtime user of Terminal on the Mac, a colleague recently recommended iTerm2.   I had a play around with it, and the same colleague gave me his Profiles JSON file.  In vim, I was able to do a global replace of his username with mine, to change the ssh profiles.  However, he uses a white background and black text, and the font is far too small for me.

Is there any way to know what to change in the JSON, which is 16,334 lines long, so there's no question of doing it manually?

I essentially want to make all of my ssh sessions open with a dark green background, yellow text and with the entire window enlarged to where it would be if I did roughly eight presses on CMD+.

Thank you.

Comment: Make a copy of the JSON file, edit one session, and compare the resulting JSON file with the copy. This should give you a good idea of what to change in each session.

Comment: Second that. And use an editor that can do bulk replacements. From what you tell, it should be sufficient to adjust the lines starting with `"Normal Font" : "...` to a font(and size) you are comfortable with.